# OAuth2 tokens for use with Google Analytics API

Tags: google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I have a site that I have tagged using Google Analytics. I can see that the stats are being created and I can analyse them using Google Analytics web tool.

I want to extract my tagging data using the Google Analytics API but all the instructions seem to point me towards the developers console to create my OAuth2 token. My site does not appear in the list of apps that is presented, so I can't do the next step of generating my OAuth2 token.

I feel like I must be missing something obvious, but I am hitting  brick wall at the moment. How do I get the site to appear so I can see it in the developers console?

Comment: Your site won't appear in developer console its just for creating the project used to extract the data.  which programing language will you be using?

Comment: This might help: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/installed-java    Also look into using a service account instead of Oauth2.  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-java

Comment: @DaImTo - thanks very much for this - I wish you'd put it as an answer so I could give you the points :)

Comment: tried to give you some extra info to avoid link only anwser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Developer console is for registering your application, this way google knows who is using there APIs.  Your Google analytics account wont show up here because well that's not how it works.

Create a new project you will get a client_id and client secrete that are used to identify your application.  Then you use a programming language to access the API using the client id and client secret.

I am not a java programmer so i cant help you with that.  You mentioned that you want to access your own data. I recommend you look in to using a service account.  A service account can be used to grant authentication without having to prompt a user for access.  This only works when it is your own account you are accessing and the data doesn't belong to another user.  Take the service account email address and add it as a user in google analytics at the ACCOUNT level it must be the Account level.  then when you use the service account in your code you will have access.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-java